# Asynchronously issue

Tags: angularjs

**Use case:**

In my index.html. I have two ng-include directives and two custom directives.

Each directive has its src attribute defined the address to load some html snippet from another server (the custom directives have its template attribute loading the html)

I need to make sure that all directives (see the code 1,2,3) have fully loaded the html snippets before I call the fifth ng-include directive (4) to load the java-script from another server.

Right now all directives are running asynchronously and I can't be sure that the directive which loads the Javascript should always be the last one to load. I need this because if Javascript is loaded and executed before the html it wouldn't go through the html and linking it to javascript/jQuery.

I have solved this issue using a very classic way. I update a global variable whenever the html snipts are loaded and define the an ng-include directive to load the Javascript conditionally when the global variable is true indicating all other directives have loaded their html. But this is not the Angular way. I need the Angular way and btw I'm new starter on Angular.

**Index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="navigationController" >

            **(1)**<agilesites-navbar></agilesites-navbar>

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-right">
                    <div id="offcanvas-curtain" class="hidden-lg"></div>
                    <div id="contentContainer" class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                       <div ui-view="content" id="content"></div>
                    </div>
                    **(2)**<agilesites-sidebar></agilesites-sidebar>
                </div>
            </div>

            **(3)**<ng-include src="''+API_HOST+'api/cms/footer'" onload="cmsResourceLoadingStatus(true)"></ng-include>
            **(4)**<ng-include src="''+API_HOST+'api/cms/javascript'"  ng-if="cmsResourceLoadingCompleted"></ng-include>
        </div>
```

Custom directive (agilesites-sidebar):

```
angular.module('newhorizonsApp')
    .directive('agilesitesSidebar', ['ProductTypes','$compile', function (ProductTypes,$compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,
        template: '<ng-include src="\'\'+API_HOST+\'api/cms/sidebar\'" onload="executeOnLoad();"></ng-include>',
        link: function (scope,elem){

            scope.executeOnLoad = function() {

                scope.cmsResourceLoadingStatus(true);
            };


        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Show us some code, please.

Comment: Please itemize script sequence , source and use case for each better. Explanation is very hard to follow

Comment: ok I formatted the code

Comment: Is this difficult to solve ?